# Could not find com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk

Tags: android, maven, sdk, opentok, tokbox

Do you have an issue with your tokbox maven's ? 
Because since this morning i can't compile my project, i have this error :

Could not find any matches for com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.8.+

also after upgrade sdk version to 2.12.1 it's same

The maven links are in 404 : 
https://bintray.com/tokbox/maven/opentok-android-sdk
http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven

Thanks

Comment: I am also having issues with the maven repo and tokbox SDK. I just think it's down today, and hopefully they'll have it back up soon. In the meantime, I think you can just download the SDK and include it in your project if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We’re currently having an issue with one of our providers so the OpenTok Android SDK is unavailable at: https://bintray.com/tokbox/maven/opentok-android-sdk.

Temporarily, you can access the OpenTok Android SDK at the following url: https://tokbox-telefonica.bintray.com/maven

We're working to resolve this immediately so I'll update this answer as we go further!

UPDATE 11/15/17 ~7:45 am PST: 
We've restored the original URL: https://tokbox.bintray.com/maven/

Answer (score 3):

To add an actual dependency, you're most likely using the wrong URL. Try this one instead:

```
compile 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.12.0'
```

In addition, you need to define the URL for the maven repo in the project-level build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       maven {
           ...
           url 'https://tokbox.bintray.com/maven'
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: If this solution won't work then Download project from GitHub and add it as Module dependency in your project

Comment: @BabulPatel assuming OP's gradle files are set up correct, adding the gradle dependency shouldn't be a problem. Your solution works too though, but it's slightly harder than dealing with Gradle .

Comment: Hi @Zoe this solution don't work. Do you have a link to sdk on github ? the tokbox support team need also to fix this, yesterday it worked ...

Answer (score 1):

Opentok suggests to use this url as workaround until they fix the issue.

maven { url 'https://tokbox-telefonica.bintray.com/maven' }